# Get Hours and Minutes from NSDatePicker - Swift

Tags: swift, nsdatepicker

Hi so i making something where a user enters a TIME into NSDatePicker so i can get the value and store it into a string for later use. I have connected the date picker with an outlet and im trying to get the value to export with no luck! Please help!

The NSDatePicker is setup to only show time like this 12:00 am

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get **date** property from Date Picker and use it together with NSCalendar to extract information.

Try something like this piece of code

```
func getHourFromDatePicker(datePicker:UIDatePicker) -> String
{
    let date = datePicker.date

    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Hour, NSCalendarUnit.Minute] , fromDate: date)

    return "\(components.hour):\(components.minute)"
}
```

And then, invoke it as follow:

```
var strTime = getHourFromDatePicker(myDatePicker)
print(strTime)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the selected date with [`dateValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDatePicker_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSDatePicker/dateValue). You might want to use NSCalendar's [`components(_:fromDate:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/components:fromDate:) if you only care about hour and minute.